# Trying to aggregate data using a mixture of group by, rank and dense rank with no luck

Tags: sql, group-by, amazon-redshift, rank, dense-rank

I am battling some pretty horrendous legacy data sets and need to aggregate the data so it is more usable. I am not too sure whether I need rank, dense_rank or group by or a combination of the 3. (or something new).

The data is structured like:

```
--[Table:]
hashed_id | visit_id | datetime            | page_name | ...
----------+----------+---------------------+-----------+-----
abc       | 1        | 2019-01-01 00:00:01 | page1     | ...
abc       | 1        | 2019-01-01 00:00:02 | page1     | ...
abc       | 1        | 2019-01-01 00:00:03 | page1     | ...
abc       | 1        | 2019-01-01 00:00:10 | page1     | ...
abc       | 1        | 2019-01-01 00:00:20 | page2     | ...
abc       | 1        | 2019-01-01 00:00:32 | page2     | ...
abc       | 1        | 2019-01-01 00:00:53 | page1     | ...
abc       | 1        | 2019-01-01 00:00:54 | page1     | ...
```

and I want

```
--[Table:]
hashed_id | visit_id | datetime            | page_name | ...
----------+----------+---------------------+-----------+-----
abc       | 1        | 2019-01-01 00:00:01 | page1     | ...
abc       | 1        | 2019-01-01 00:00:20 | page2     | ...
abc       | 1        | 2019-01-01 00:00:53 | page1     | ...
```

I have tried using rank, dense rank and group by but don't seem to get the desired results. Am I being an idiot :)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lag()` to get the first time a page appears that is different from the preceding page:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(page_name) over (partition by hashed_id, visit_id order by datetime) as prev_page_name
      from t
     ) t
where prev_page_name is null or prev_page_name <> page_name
```

Comment: Thank you, I was unaware of the lag function and it seemed to do the trick! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

select to your data  seems you need a join between the table and the min(datetime) group by  hashed_id, visit_id

```
select * from my_table  m 
inner join  (
  select  hashed_id, visit_id, min(datetime) min_date 
  from my_table
  group by   hashed_id, visit_id
 ) t 0n t.hashed_id = m.hashed_id 
    and t.visit_id = m.visit_id 
        and t.min_date = m.datetime
```

Comment: It seems that this creates issues with return page view within the same visit. The lag function seems to do that trick, thanks for your help anyway!